# Define font style as a variable

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to define different font styles (in gnuplot), so that I can refer to them later by an index instead of repeating them all every time, for example:
font1 = font "Helvetica,12" ;
font2 = font "Verdana, 12"     and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use macros for this.

```
set macros
```

With this enabled (in version 5 by default), you can define string variables which are replaced in a command with their content before the command is executed, like

```
set macros
Helvetica = 'font "Helvetica, 12"'
Verdana = 'font " Verdana, 12"'

set title "My title" @Verdana
set xlabel "My x-label" @Helvetica
plot x
```