# Call Gnuplot passing style as parameter

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Recently I discovered how to pass arguments to gnuplot, so I can do:

```
gnuplot -e "filename='../2038/data'; width='640'; height='480'" plot.plt
```

Where `plot.plt`:

```
set term png size width, height

set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
set format x "%b"

set datafile separator ";"

set output filename.'_full.png'
plot filename.'.csv' using 1:3 w dots

set output filename.'.png'
set yrange [-0.1:3]
plot filename.'.csv' using 1:3 w dots
```

Then I tried to pass in the style:

```
gnuplot -e "filename='../2038/data'; width='640'; height='480'; style='w dots'" plot.plt
```

with `plot.plt`

```
set term png size width, height

set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
set format x "%b"

set datafile separator ";"

set output filename.'_full.png'
plot filename.'.csv' using 1:3 style

set output filename.'.png'
set yrange [-0.1:3]
plot filename.'.csv' using 1:3 style
```

This time I was unsuccessful. How should I proceed?

Reference:

[How to pass command line argument to gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328603/how-to-pass-command-line-argument-to-gnuplot)

[Concatenate 2 strings in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138334/concatenate-2-strings-in-gnuplot)

Comment: Use macros for the style, `plot ... @style`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30427834/2604213

Comment: I think you'll have to `set macros` before using the above method

Comment: @GavinPortwood Since 5.0 macros are enabled by default.