# set dynamic key position in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I use `set key top right;` to manually set plot keys in Gnuplot 5.2. However, I have many plots with different datasets and I need to put the key at different positions. Different corners of the plot. I wish to change this dynamically within Gnuplot. How can I do it? Is there something like:

```
pos = "left";
set key top $pos;
```

available to define a position?

Comment: `eval("set key top " . pos)`

Comment: `set key top @pos`, `@pos` is called macro in gnuplot terminology, see e.g. also https://stackoverflow.com/a/30427834/2604213